# Как добавить многомерный массив JS

Tags: массивы, javascript

Здравствуйте, как добавить многомерный массив в JS, примерно такого вида:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(9) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["type"]=>
    string(2) "23"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var arr = [];
arr.push({
    'id': 4,
    'type': 'C'
  });
```

Comment: @zhenyab 

а как обратится к элементу?

Comment: var type = arr[0].type;

Comment: или var type = arr[0]['type']

Answer (score 0):

Вариант 1:

> var arr = {    0: {
>      'id': 2,
>      'type': 'A'    },    1: {
>      'id': 3,
>      'type': 'B'    },    2: {
>      'id': 4,
>      'type': 'C'
>     } };

Вариант 2:
    var arr2 = [
      {
        'id': 2,
        'type': 'A'
      },
      {
        'id': 3,
        'type': 'B'
      },
      {
        'id': 4,
        'type': 'C'
      }
    ];

Comment: @Konstantin Gusev

А как при помощи push?

Comment: Смотреть ниже